# How should one interpret the printed representation of integers in Emacs Lisp?

Tags: characters, numbers

I'm getting to grips with Emacs Lisp in GNU Emacs 25.3.2. While trying to understand the printed representation of integers I got confused by the following echo area output produced by `C-x` `C-e`:

```
10
-> 10 (#o12, #xa, ?\C-j)
```

I gather from the [manual section](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Integer-Basics.html#Integer-Basics) describing the read syntax for integers that `#o12` and `#xa` indicate the octal and hex representations of the decimal number `10` respectively.

What does `?\C-j` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `?\C-j` is the character representation of 10, in this case it's the same as control-j.

For other values, it's more natural, for example 65, which is the ASCII value of `A`:

```
65
-> 65 (#o101, #x41, ?A)
```

Comment: Ah, right. So the [ASCII character](http://www.asciitable.com) corresponding to the decimal number 10 is the LF new line character, and _within emacs_ the key combo to produce that symbol is control-j?

Comment: Yes, within emacs, and within most, if not all, consoles as well.

Comment: For more information see `M-: (info "(elisp) Basic Char Syntax")`

Comment: @AndrewL Note that J is the 10th letter of the alphabet. This is not a coincidence; it is used to determine the print representations of all non-printable ASCII characters, and often these are used for keybindings too (control-C is interrupt because the ASCII interrupt character has code 3).